# How can I wrap my javascript rails assets in Immediately Invoked Function Expressions (IIFE)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I know that's it's best practice to isolate your javascript code into IIFEs. This also allows me to make use of the "use strict" magic string.

However, Adding this to every file by hand is not only cumbersome but prone to human error (aka forgetting).

It seems like the sprockets preprocessing would be ideal but the only example I could find was from 2 years ago and it doesn't appear to work:
http://eviltrout.com/2013/02/25/iife-in-rails.html

Does anyone have a working solution? Is the a gem I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I think it did work and I missed a small detail:

> One caveat – if you change the IIFE code, you’ll have to clear your tmp directory in order to get your assets to recompile.

Once I clear that out it worked beautifully.